# Is there way to span dependencies across Tests in TestNG?

Tags: java, automated-tests, testng

I'm on TestNG 6.8.5.  Is there a way to span either dependsOnGroups or dependsOnMethods across Tests, rather than just within a single Test?

I have a Suite configured like this with two Tests and a bunch of other Tests between them:

```
<suite name="ConfigurationSuite">

    <test name="DeviceMgmtTest_Setup" >
        <classes>
            <class name="com.yay.DeviceMgmtTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="createDevice" />
                    <include name="discoverDevice" />
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <!-- A whole bunch of other very sequential
         and long-running tests go here... -->

    <test name="DeviceMgmtTest_TearDown" >
        <classes>
            <class name="com.yay.DeviceMgmtTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="deleteDevice" />
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

My test class has methods configured like this:

```
@Test(groups = { "setup" })
public void createDevice() {
    // do something
}

@Test(groups = { "setup" })
public void discoverDevice() {
    // do something
}

@Test(groups = { "tearDown" }, dependsOnGroups = { "setup" })
public void deleteDevice() {
    // When TestNG reaches this method I get a
    // group "setup" does not exist type exception (see below)
}
```

But when I run the suite, the dependsOnGroups annotation fails with an error like this:

```
[ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException:
[ERROR] DependencyMap::Method .... DeviceMgmtTest depends on nonexistent group "setup"
```

Maybe I'm not understanding something correctly about how to configure my Suite (I'm very new to TestNG), but separating these areas of concern out into separate Tests makes sense to me.

Thanks for any guidance or suggestions!

EDIT: One solution I'm considering is grabbing the TestNG ITestContext and navigating to the parent Suite, and then checking the status of a previous test.  I just thought there might be a more elegant TestNG convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to depend on a method from different classes.

However, it is definitely possible to depend on a group from different classes.  If you want to use XML, this is the documentation for that: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependencies-in-xml

Comment: I believe your first statement may be what I need to know... in my example, I'm not crossing Test classes, but I definitely would be wanting to do that eventually.

My base problem here is that when TestNG instantiates the Test, the groups created consist only of methods defined in the currently-running <test> xml, rather than all tests in the entire <suite> scope.

Thanks for your input, MrTi...

Comment: You need to define your groups in the XML.  Check out this documentation: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups  You could change your  `@Test`s with the setup group in to `@BeforeClass` or `@BeforeMethod`

Comment: Thanks for the lead -- I tried this but get the same result "nonexistent group 'setup'".  I just found a quote by Cedric Beust saying, "Dependencies only work within the same <test> tag".  So, I guess this just isn't going to work for me... https://groups.google.com/d/msg/testng-users/KrhnfKKwqt0/l4YGS0ujsuoJ

Comment: Hi Nathan. I'd love to know how you implemented
_"definitely possible to depend on a group from different classes"_.
I put my group dependencies in the `testng.xml` file just like your link to the docs showed and am still getting the
_"depends on nonexistent group"_
error message.

Comment: I guess in `testng.xml` I was not including the classes the dependencies were in, /facepalm.

Answer (score 1):

I think based on what your sample code is ..all you want is that your teardown should execute after your setup and your tests.  You might want to chuck dependson altogether and try using preserve-order = true.  As such you need not even set it coz that's the default and testng runs your tests in the order that they are found in your xml.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  My concern is that I don't want the tear down to run if the setup fails.  We often need to re-run setup tests after doing some mucking around with the physical hardware.  Maybe I just need to make my tear down methods smarter...